# How to prevent server not found causing android app crash?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection to connect to my remote server. Now in case the server is down, the app crashes.

How can i handle this more gracefully using a toast or a new activity?

Here is my code,

```
public class SignIn extends AsyncTask<Bundle,Void,Void> {

    public SignIn(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bundle... params) {
        userData = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        URL url;

        try{
            String base_url = "http://10.0.0.11:8080/SignIn";
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(base_url).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("email", userData.getString("email"))
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", userData.getString("password"))
                    .build();

            url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
            //Log.e("URL",url.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            //Some code to read the Input stream and parse JSON not included.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Network Error", e.toString(), e);

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Logcat output

```
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://52.0.81.130:8080/LoggerLog-1.0/SignIn?email=a&password=a
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://52.0.81.130:8080/LoggerLog-1.0/SignIn?email=a&password=a
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at com.truebros.healthlog.LoginStuff.SignIn.doInBackground(SignIn.java:105)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at com.truebros.healthlog.LoginStuff.SignIn.doInBackground(SignIn.java:21)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
03-29 08:42:48.596: E/Network Error(1213):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-29 08:42:48.606: E/Parsing error(1213): SignIn.java
```

Comment: add the toast show/redirect to other activity operations in catch block and try to close urlconnection,reader

Comment: Please post the logcat as there you can see the exception/error which causes your app to crash.

Comment: Your app should not crash. Not by this code. Maybe by the Log in the catch. Or if userData is null. Try without.

Comment: I have added the logcat output

Answer (score 0):

Use setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION) and setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET) in your URLConnection. This will help to manage server down and network problem. For more check below link [1]http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)
[2]http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)

Comment: it crashes as soon as execute the async task. You sure timeout will work?

Comment: connection timeout work well if server network is slow . please also share your error log.

Comment: i have added the logcat output. And my server has been shut down. I want to handle the server shut down scenario.